# Effectively using singing games for vocal training

Tags: practice, voice, software

What are productive ways to use the "Rock Band" video game as part of a vocal training regimen?

Are there any bad habits/practices that singing along with this type of game tends to promote?

Comment: I believe that this is different from [this similar question](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6219/is-it-possible-to-use-video-games-to-help-improve-ones-singing)  in that the answer, will (hopefully) focus on how to make the best use of these games.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how far a vocal game will get you, at least the ones that exist now. The main problem  is they cannot give you feedback beyond pitch (and maybe rhythm). So any errors or deficiencies in technique may never get corrected.

That said, if you have a basic understanding of technique already, then games could be a fun way to practice.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to have a basic understanding of vocal technique in order to have any chance of improvement as they do not provide any advice and vocal coaching. I would recommand personnaly to take lessons or online lessons. Self-teaching yourself singing could get you real bad habits which could impact your progress dramaticaly.